# quarkus @ObservesAsync invoke Uni

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x, mutiny

What's the best way to invoke Uni in an async observer? It would be great if I could just return Uni but unfortunately that doesn't work.

```
void observe(@ObservesAsync MyEvent event) {
    Uni<Object> task;
}
```

Comment: Async observers are just synchronous methods executed on an extra thread. That is, there's no way to signal to the CDI container that the observer execution has finished; it always assumes that when the method returns, it has completed. You could possibly block on the `Uni` (using `await()`), if that's fine in your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ladicek, you can:

1. use a synchronous observer and block until termination
2. use a synchronous observer and "trigger" the async operation using a fire-and-forget approach
3. use an async observer (while it's not strictly async, it just runs on another thread) and produce a `CompletionStage`

**1) synchronous observer and block until termination**

```java
void observe(@Observes MyEvent event) {
    Uni<Void> uni = ...;
    uni.await().indefinitely();

}
```

**2) synchronous observer and trigger the async operation using a fire-and-forget approach**

```java
void observe(@Observes MyEvent event) {
    Uni<Void> uni = ...;
    uni.subscribeAsCompletionStage(); // Fire and forget, no error reporting

}
```

Or:

```java
void observe(@Observes MyEvent event) {
    Uni<Void> uni = ...;
    uni.subscribe().with(success -> ..., failure -> log(failure));
}
```

**Async observer and produce a `CompletionStage`**

```java
void observe(@Observes MyEvent event) {
    Uni<Void> uni = ...;
    return uni.subscribeAsCompletionStage();
}
```